# Static member inside the form

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

In my project on the WindowsForms, if I have a **static** instance inside the form, when I'm opening my form at the first time, it works. But if I'll close it and open again, the form will be empty. Why can it be?

```
public partial class Computer : Form
    {
        static Indicators indicators = new Code.Indicators();
    }
```

**P.S.** I'm making it static, because I want to save it's value after the form will be closed.

**Edit 1: Opening the form**

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Computer computer = new Computer();
            computer.ShowDialog();
        }
```

**Edit 2: Computer Form**

```
namespace WF
{
    public partial class Computer : Form
    {
        static Code.Indicators indicators = new Code.Indicators();

        public Computer()
        {
            if (indicators.isComputerAlreadyRunning == false)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Computer1;
                indicators.isComputerAlreadyRunning = true;
            }
        }

        // My not successful try to save the value of the variable
        public Code.Indicators ShowForm()
        {
            return new Code.Indicators(indicators.isComputerAlreadyRunning);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the form will be empty". In what way is it empty?

Comment: What do you mean by "the form will be empty"? Do you mean to say that the `indicators` variable will be null when the form is opened again?

Comment: When I open the form in the second time, there is no icons and buttons on it

Comment: Note that you can access fields of a Form after it's been closed, so I question whether using a static is the correct approach here.

Comment: How are you opening the form the second time? (What's the code?)

Comment: Also, what is this `indicators`? Is it a control on the form?

Comment: @SFLee I have the main form and button on it. And with that button I'm opening my form with the error. Code in **Edit 1**

Comment: @SFLee Indicators is an independent class, which contains variables

Comment: Can you show us the code for your `Computer` form? Namely, the constructor and the form_load event handler?

Comment: @SFLee Yes, in the **Edit 2**.

Comment: You probably don't want to use a static variable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the constructor in the `Computer` class, the `indicators.isComputerAlreadyRunning` is set to true the first time the form is created.

So when `Computer` is created the second time, the `if` condition will fail and the whole `if` block will be skipped. That means your `InitializeComponent();` won't get run and hence nothing in the form will shows up.

Put the `InitializeComponent();` outside the `if` clause to make it work.

Comment: Hmm... really =) So easy

Comment: +1 for your patience and insistant asking before you answered

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that static members work well with the Windows Form lifecycle.

I suggest you make `Indicators` a normal instance member of your form. To preserve state beyond the life of a form you can copy your state from the form and copy it back to the form when you open it.

```
// Keep this in the proper place 
var indicators = new Code.Indicators();

...

// Copy back and forth for the life time of the form
using (var form = new Computer())
{
    form.Indicators.AddRange(indicators);
    form.Close += (s, e) => 
        {
            indicators.Clear();
            indicators.AddRange(form.Indicators);
        }
}

...
```

Comment: @SFLee You are right. As I stated, static and windows form lifecycle probably don't work well together. Static can often make problems with your software design. Investigating the root cause of the issue is certainly a good idea. Improving the design might be an even better idea.